# Alter a query using hook_views_query_alter() to filter a view by month

Tags: views, 8

I successfully created a view gathering, let's say, events, sorted by date.  I also created exposed filters so one could filter the view.

I'm attempting to create another exposed filter that would filter the data on their field_date, but only by month. I quickly understood that this feature is not provided out of the box, so I managed to implement `hook_views_query_alter()` in the .views_execution.inc file.

This is what it contains.

```
function djm_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query){
    if($view->id() == 'calendar'){
        $date_format = $query->getDateFormat("node__field_precise_date.field_precise_date_value", "m");
        $query->addWhere(5, $date_format, 12, "=");
    }
}
```

`$date_format` should return `DATE_FORMAT('node__field_precise_date.field_precise_date_value', '%m')`.  The thing is that (I inspected the query my view outputs) the view totally strips my parentheses, percentage signs and, I guess, any special character, so it becomes `DATE_FORMATnode__field_precise_date.field_precise_date_valuem`.

Has anyone ever experience something like this?  I can't figure what to do to "fix" this. Am I using the right hook?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get my code working, if anyone is stucked at the same point, you have to use `addWhereExpression` instead of `addWhere`.  Here's what it looks like overall.

```
function HOOK_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query){
    if($view->id() == 'calendar'){
        $definition = array(
            'table' => 'node__field_precise_date',
            'field' => 'entity_id',
            'left_table' => 'node_field_data',
            'left_field' => 'nid',
            'extra' => [ // These are extra conditions views adds by default, I just copied them so it looks like any filter.
                0 =>[
                    'field' => 'deleted',
                    'value' => 0
                ],
                1 => [
                    'left_field' => 'langcode',
                'field' => 'langcode'
                ]
            ]
        );
        $join = Views::pluginManager('join')->createInstance('standard', $definition);

        $query->addRelationship('node__field_precise_date', $join, 'node_field_data');
        // ouptuts "LEFT JOIN {node__field_precise_date} node__field_precise_date ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_precise_date.entity_id AND (node__field_precise_date.deleted = '0' AND node__field_precise_date.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)"

        $date_format = $query->getDateFormat("node__field_precise_date.field_precise_date_value", "m")." = :value";
        $query->addWhereExpression(2, $date_format, [":value" => 12]); // Where 12 is the month I need.
    }
}
```

I'm still opened to better ideas so feel free to share them !